# Адаптивность сайта на устройствах iphone

Tags: css3, html5, адаптивная-верстка

**Всем привет!**
При верстке сайта, тестировал его через google и firefox в инструментах для разработчиков. Все отображалось корректно, под ipad, iphone 5/6/7... Все выглядело замечательно, но как только решил протестировать его, зайдя с телефонов, был в шоке. На iphone устройстве - все криво, коряво, перекошено. Потом я зашел с андроида и все выглядело как и задумывалось, все отображалось корректно, как и при проверках в браузерах.
 Что это может значить и как с этим бороться?